# Make Gnome shortcuts available to other users

Tags: gnome, shortcuts

I have used Alacarte to add some shortcuts to my games start folder. Now I would like to make these shortcuts available for all users. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your users's menu settings are stored in `~/.config/menus/`.  All you have to do is copy yours to the desired users.

Answer (score 2):

To complite aperson's one - just copying files is not enough. You would also want to set proper permissions and ownership.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the appropriate `.desktop` files to `/usr/share/applications`.